# CXF response has unqualified namespace

Tags: soap, jaxb, cxf, xml-namespaces

I am using CXF 2.3.0 for hosting a services, but the response from the service is
shown below

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
     <responseElement xmlns="http://xxx/yyyy.wsdl/types/">
             <result>
```

But desired is

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns0="http://xxx/yyyy.wsdl/types/">
   <env:Body>
      <ns0:responseElement>
         <ns0:result>
```

I am having a package-info class which declares the element namespace to be qualified.
Is there any thing else I need to do?

Comment: Both are semantically identical. You shouldn't care where the namespaces are declared, as long as they're consistent and correct, which both of the above are.

Comment: Yes I understand...but is there a way to do it ? I am recreating the services and it is required to be exactly the same

Comment: You may find the following article helpful:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since CXF uses JAXB for handling XML serialization, you should use standard JAXB methods for controlling how namespace prefixes are allocated. That is, you use something like this in a suitably-placed `package-info.java`:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    xmlns = { 
        @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(
            prefix = "ns0", 
            namespaceURI="http://xxx/yyyy.wsdl/types/")
    }
)
package your.pkg.name;
```

Comment: Also, you might get different placement of `xmlns` attributes anyway; different XML serializers tend to vary in this area, and it's hard to change their behavior (it's not supposed to matter, after all…)

Comment: Does it have any issues with Solaris OS ? Because it is not working with SUn solaris alone.All other setups are same... It works in a Linux box but not in Sun Solaris

Comment: it worked thanks!!! just a really small note: at the originally generated wsdl2java I already had at the XmlSchema 2 elements: namespace and elementFormDefault, so I needed to keep those also